# appending values to dictionary in for loop

Tags: python

Just cant get this working. Any help is highly appreciated.

```
dict = {}
for n in n1:
    if # condition #
        dict[key] = []
        dict[key].append(value)
        print dict
```

This is printing something like this

> {'k1':['v1']} and {'k1':['v2']}

I have few other nested for loops down this code, which will be using this dict and the dict has only the latest key value pairs i.e. `{'k1':'v2'}`

I am looking for something like `{'k1':['v1','v2']}`

Please suggest a solution without using `setdefault`

Answer (score 12):

You can also check key existence before assign.

```
dict = {}
for n in n1:
    if # condition #
        if key not in dict:
            dict[key] = []
        dict[key].append(value)
        print dict
```

Comment: this answer helped me solve a problem I was working on all day. So thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Give [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) a try:

```
#example below is in the docs.
from collections import defaultdict

s = [('yellow', 1), ('blue', 2), ('yellow', 3), ('blue', 4), ('red', 1)]
d = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in s:
    d[k].append(v)

print(sorted(d.items()))
[('blue', [2, 4]), ('red', [1]), ('yellow', [1, 3])]
```

the `d = defaultdict(list)` line is setting the keys values to be an empty dictionary by default and appending the value to the list in the loop.

Comment: When I try `d = defaultdict(list)` in my dictionary, it gives error in the line `for k, v in s`, saying `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)`. My dictionary looks like `{'branch': {'NumberOfTimes': 4, 'Score': 34},
 'transfer': {'NumberOfTimes': 1, 'Score': 5},
 'deal': {'NumberOfTimes': 2, 'Score': 10}, ... }`. Would you know what's the issue? I tried `d = defaultdict(dict)`, but that doesn't solve the issue either.

Comment: Your outer structure is a dictionary.  Each one of the values of your keys should be of type "list". right now each or your values is a dictionary as well.  But since you have things in the list that need a order or a name I would suggest creating a type of namedTuple to store "numberOfTimes" and "Score", then creating a dd = defaultdict(my_namedtuple)

Answer (score 3):

The problem with the code is it creates an empty list for 'key' each time the for loop runs. You need just one improvement in the code:

```
dict = {}
dict[key] = []
for n in n1:
   if # condition #
       dict[key].append(value)
       print dict
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
a=[['a',1],['b',2],['c',1],['a',2],['b',3],['a',3]]
d={}
for i in a:
    print (i)
    if i[0] not in d:
       d[i[0]]= [i[1]]
    else:
        d[i[0]].append(i[1])
print (d)



OP : {'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [2, 3], 'c': [1]}
```

Comment: Can you provide an explanation on how this solves the problem?

Comment: first create an empty dictionary,  take the given list in for loop then check the keys are in dictionary or not if there append the value else create a new pair

Answer (score 0):

You can use try except block in your loop.

```
another_dict = {}

for key, value in example_dict.items():
    try:
        another_dict[key].append(value)
    except:
        another_dict[key] = list(value)
```

Easy and clean.